# How can I find which Control-Command keys are mapped to particular programs?

Tags: keyboard, iterm

I am using iTerm2 under High Sierra 10.13.6. iTerm2 lets me assign Control-Command key combos to particular actions. This mostly works fine, but at least two of these do nothing: Control-Command-B and Control-Command-D. I suspect they are being grabbed by something at the system level. However, manually walking through all of System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts didn't show anything for these two.

Is there a way to get a list of all key combinations and map them to what they are (or are not) assigned to?

Comment: You're correct that those two shortcuts are system editing. You can disable the Cmd+Ctrl+D combo using https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/how-do-i-disable-the-command-control-d-word-definition-keyboard-shortcut-in-os-x

Answer (score 3):

There are a few apps out there which are meant to help show the available keyboard commands. The only ones I can remember right now are:

1. [KeyCue](https://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/) which is €19.99 but does have a trial. I suspect this is probably the best of the bunch, although it’s the most expensive.
2. [CheatSheet](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) is another one, which is free, although it doesn't show nearly as many shortcuts as KeyCue does.

(If I can remember others I will edit this to add them)

Unfortunately, when I tried KeyCue and CheatSheet, neither of them showed anything for `⌃⌘D` or `⌃⌘B`.

I know that `⌃⌘D`is used for the system dictionary (highlight a word, press `⌃⌘D` and you’ll get a dictionary lookup for it). But I don’t see a preference for it in System Preferences to allow you to disable it or re-assign it.

Also `⌃⌘B` doesn’t seem to do anything on my Mac, so that may be specific to some app that you have installed.

Be sure to check the ”Services” area of Keyboard preferences:

[image]

That’s where I usually find the culprit when something has stolen a keyboard shortcut that I want to use.

Comment: If neither of them even found ⌃⌘D, that's not helpful. And I did look through Services, and have nothing selected at all.

Comment: It's possible that the program that is taking/'hijacking' the shortcuts is put together poorly and isn't doing them in a way that Apple/these programs can recognize.

Have you tried to maybe create a shortcut using the same combination and in keyboard shortcuts and seeing if anything pops up telling you you have a conflict? Also, try to close down all your startup programs and check activity monitor to see if you have apps that you don't recognize/might be using them

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **Matt Sephton's** correct answer is hidden as "comment" ***under your basic Question***:

> You're correct that those two shortcuts are system editing. You can
>   disable the Cmd+Ctrl+D combo using
>   [apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/…](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/how-do-i-disable-the-command-control-d-word-definition-keyboard-shortcut-in-os-x) – [Matt Sephton](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/15281/matt-sephton) *Sep 25 at 12:21*